# How to save the return of viz.visualize_image_attr as image Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, tuples, visualization, machine-learning-model

I need to use the return value of

```
viz.visualize_image_attr(fa_attr_without_max[0].cpu().detach().permute(1, 2, 0).numpy(), sign="all", title="Integrated Gradients")
```

as an image.

This method returns: `2-element tuple of *figure, **axis*`; their data type is `matplotlib.pyplot.figure`

I tried plt and searched for convert tuple into image but no result found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [matplotlib.pyplot.savefig](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html)

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

example = (x, y) #Assume these are matplotlib figures returned from your func
example[0].savefig('foo.png')
example[1].savefig('foo2.pdf')
```

Comment: this works for me thank you, now I need to reuse this image in the function ----   plt_fig = viz.visualize_image_attr(fa_attr_without_max[0].cpu().detach().permute(1, 2, 0).numpy(), sign="all", title="Integrated Gradients")
    
    
    plt_fig[0].savefig('D:/models/' +"new.jpg", format='jpg')

       return 'new.jpg'  but it gives me error

Comment: What is the error you get? I don't think savefig() returns anything.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example as an extra knowledge:

```
`u, x = viz.visualize_image_attr_multiple(
np.transpose(attributions_ig_nt.squeeze().cpu().detach().numpy(), (1,2,0)),
np.transpose(transformed_img.squeeze().cpu().detach().numpy(), (1,2,0)),
["original_image", "heat_map"],
["all", "positive"],
#cmap=default_cmap,
cmap="viridis",
show_colorbar=True)`

`u.savefig('foo.png') `
```

x is 'numpy.ndarray' and has no attribute 'savefig'.

x has the following info:

```
`array([<Axes: >, <Axes: >], dtype=object)`
```